# 3D Unity characters without Maya

Tags: unity, maya

I have been writing 2D iOS games for a while and I'm looking into getting into 3D. I want to know if Maya is required for making 3D sprites or if you can easily make your 3D sprites using just Unity 3D.

They won't be detailed, just about the size / shape and detail level of *Crossy Road* sprites

[image]

Comment: In 3D objects are no longer sprites but models (just to prevent confusion). There are how ever sprites in 3D called billboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maya isn't the only 3D modeling package supported by Unity. Basically, anything that exports to .fbx will work (Unity imports that file format).

The other most common options are 3ds max and Blender, the latter of which is open-source. But again, any tool that exports to .fbx (which is most 3D modeling software) will work.

Answer (score 1):

While Unity doesn't come with any 3D modeling tools, you could (with a bit of work) achieve that visual style just by using the primitives built into it.

Be advised, there are a variety of other 3D Modeling packages that you can use (other than Maya), that are far more affordable (see: free) for a new 3D modeler.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: [Anim8or](http://www.anim8or.com/) is a 3D modeling and character animation program in development for over decade. It is very accessible for beginners and hobbyists. It is taught in schools and a lot of tutorials exist.

Example resource:

http://cyberdog.wikispaces.com/Anim8or-Saucer101

Manual:

http://www.anim8or.com/learn/manual/index.html